# Why I am getting include_path warning with zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a zend tutorial zip but when i am running it i am getting two warnings that are listed below

```
Warning: include(/var/www/html/zendapp/module/Admin/config/../view/layout/layout.phtml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/zendapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php on line 506


Warning: include(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/zendapp/module/Admin/config/../view/layout/layout.phtml' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/zendapp/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php on line 506
```

Please help me I tried over google but still unable to find any solution.

I got it in `Admin/config/module/module.config.php` has 'template_map' array that has

```
'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'admin' => __DIR__ . '/../view'
        ),
    ),
```

and the location of layout.phtml is `var/www/html/zendapp/module/Application/view/layout/layout.phtml`

Comment: The messages seem pretty self-explanatory to me?

Comment: @JonStirling I am getting only these lines in logs what should i do ?

Comment: Fix them. Stop trying to use template files that don't exist.

Comment: @JonStirling please recheck my question i have update something.

Comment: However you look at it, the path is wrong. Fix the path in the configuration file.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois :- I downloaded it from here http://www.iprogrammerindia.in/crud-operations-zend-framework-2/ can you please check is it working or not ? or if you have any other zend 2 or zend 3 tutorials link then please suggest me I want to understand its crud operation.